# Accessing a XAMPP mysql via Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm attempting to use mysql after only having worked with sqlite in the past.

I've installed `XAMPP` on Linux (ubuntu) and have `mysql` up and running fine (seems like that with phpMyadmin at least). However, I'm having trouble getting the MySQLdb (the python lib) working {installed this using apt}.
to be exact:

```py
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",db="opfine")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 170, in __init_
  ...
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
```

> OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through
>   socket '/var
>       /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

I'm guessing

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

means its expecting some sort of local installation (i.e. not within `XAMPP`), but I can't figure out how to go about modding this to get it to work with the `XAMMP` flavor of `mysql`.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the record (and thanks to a pointer from Igancio), I found that the below works (terrible I didn't think of this before):

```
db=MySQLdb.connect(
   user="root"
  ,passwd=""
  ,db="my_db"
  ,unix_socket="/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock")
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that you didn't start the MySQL server, or it's configured to not use a domain socket.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue using and look for your SQL configuration file my.cnf.

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

and use socket as parameter:

```
mysql://read:read@localhost/phonehome?unix_socket=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

In my case:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://read:read@localhost/phonehome?unix_socket=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock'
```